# debugging CUDA code

Tags: c++, c, cuda

i am using Nsight along with VS 2008 to debug my cuda code.
I have 2 Geforce GTX 460 SE cards in my computer.
i read Nsight's user guide and updated Nvidia Control panel as stated in the guide.
but i still have a problem. in my code when i set `cudaSetDevice(0);` i get an error in nsight stating that i cannot debug since the device is attached to a monitor, which is true.
but when i set `cudaSetDevice(1);` and start cuda debugging, nsight gives no errors, but the program does not break at the breakpoint that i put in the code!.
does anybody know whats wrong?

Comment: have you set the -G0 flag in VS to enable debug information in the compiled code?

Comment: aaah that was it! thanks a million my friend :)

Comment: Jawad Masood: Repost your comment as a reply so that the original poster can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `-G0` flag in the **CUDA Build Rule** to enable debug information in the compiled code. Your breakpoint should be hit after that.

(Reply contributed originally by Jawad Masood, so I have made the reply Community Wiki.)